# Dynamic sql in table valued functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a function that returns a table with the result of a substring, but this script must be dynamic where the name of the table must be passed through parameters as well as the join and where parameters.

Here is a sample of the script that does not work:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION XXXX.XXXXXXX 
(
    @pIntegracion int, 
    @PatameterName varchar(max),
    @pJsonProyecto NVARCHAR(50),
    @pField VARCHAR(50),
    @CondicionJoin varchar (max),
    @CondicionWhere varchar (max),
    @pUuid NVARCHAR (50),
    @pTable VARCHAR(max)

)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (
    Uuid varchar(MAX)
   ,IdProyecto varchar(max) 
   ,Field__COR varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Result 
    SELECT DISTINCT P.Uuid,@pJsonProyecto,Substring(COALESCE(@pField,''), 0, Charindex('','', COALESCE(@pField,''))) AS Field_COR
    FROM @pTable P
    LEFT JOIN XXXXX A 
    @CondicionJoin
    INNER JOIN XXXXXX D
    ON (P.iddocumento = D.IdDocumento)
    @CondicionWhere
    AND D.Uuid = @pUuid
    AND D.ProcesoMetada = @pIntegracion
    AND P.EstadoConsultaApiAriba = 'Successful_File_Upload'
    AND (COALESCE(@pField,'') LIKE '%,%' OR COALESCE(@pField,'') IS NULL)

    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: I would urge to reconsider your design. When you have to resort to passing where clauses, table names and join conditions it is a clear sign that something went horribly in the design process. The only viable solution for this is to start over.

Comment: You *cannot* use dynamic SQL in a function. End of Story. There is no work around, do not pass go, do not collect £200, go directly to jail. If you have a requirement like this it, in truth, normally is an indication of a design flaw.

Comment: That's right it's a disgusting design problem that my boss gave me today, and the only way I can find to try to fix this is to create an SP

Comment: Only stored procedures can construct and execute dynamic SQL, and using stored procedure results in queries is itself difficult. If you have a legitimate need for dynamic names (and often you don't) it's far less headache inducing to leave constructing the queries to the client, especially if arbitrary `WHERE` clauses are going to be used (as there is no way for a server-side sproc to effectively parse them and guard against things like SQL injection).

Comment: I would consider going back to the boss and discussing options for finding a better approach. Most people are pretty reasonable when presented with a polite discussion about what a certain approach to something is less than ideal. But you need to have an alternative approach thought out first.

Comment: The names of tables and fields are dynamic as well as the where and join clauses since each table is different, but the same result is needed; make a substring of a couple of fields in each different table ... the problem is horrible

Comment: What you are describing is not something that should ever be done. Not only is it a security nightmare it is also a performance timebomb. This is like creating a single method in code that does everything. If you are deadset on going down this path you will have to use a stored procedure with dynamic sql.

Comment: @willysepulveda what you try to do is no better than constructing the entire SQL query on the client. In fact, it's probably easier to do so on the client. What are you *actually* trying to do though? Attach "document" metadata by joining the target table with a `meta` table? It would be a *lot* easier to create a view that does this instead, and query the view. There's no need to pass the WHERE condition to this function either, a `WHERE` can easily be added after the fuction or view call

Comment: Thank you very much for all your advice, I showed some of your comments to my boss and for performance and agility in the process it was decided to create a calculated field in the TMP table that receives the information from the source, this field will contain the necessary substring